# How can I Orchestrate Python Scripts with different virtual envs

Tags: python, airflow, schedule, orchestration

How can I use Rocketry (Python) with multiple virtual environments? I try to use Rocketry as Process Orchestrator (because it's easier than Airflow and I don't need to run on different machines).

But I don't know how to run different processes that use different virtualenvs.

(doc of rocketry: https://github.com/Miksus/rocketry)

For now, I saw that I could run some scripts before, but I think that it can be used with CLI only.

```py
from rocketry import Rocketry
from rocketry.conds import daily, secondly

app = Rocketry()

@app.task(daily)
def do_daily(): # task from virtualenv A
    ...

@app.task(daily)
def do_secondly(): # task from virtualenv B
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Could you run 1 rocketry process per virtualenv? That seems like the easiest approach.

Comment: It works, but, i want to see a global visualization... só it's not like if I want a "task scheduler", but an orchestrator.

Comment: One approach would be to run a Python subprocess using the subprocess module and `subprocess.check_call()`. Those are allowed to be in different virtualenvs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you considered other process orchestrators? Maybe something like docker-compose, but for processes:
https://github.com/F1bonacc1/process-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of Rocketry here. I have thought of at some point making a native virtual env support but at the moment doing that yourself is not difficult either. There are two options:

1. Use regular function task as a wrapper
2. Use a command task

Note that I have Windows now thus the location of your Python interpreter is somewhere else than I have if you use a different OS (I have it in `env/Scripts/python.exe`).

So basically both of these will:

1. Run the actual Rocketry app in one env/process
2. Launch a task in a separate thread (or async task)
3. Call your script using a shell command (this command calls your script with specified virtual env)

### Using a regular task

```
import subprocess

app = Rocketry()

@app.task(daily, execution="thread")
def run_script():
    subprocess.check_call(r'"env/Scripts/python.exe" C:/myscript.py')
```

Read more from subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html. Note that I used a threaded task as using `process` launches unnecessary extra child process. There is also an async-subprocess which you may also use and then set `execution="async"` if you prefer that.

### Using a command task

```
app = Rocketry()

app.task(daily, command='"env/Scripts/python.exe" C:/myscript.py', execution="thread")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

There is also an argument `cwd` (which seems to accept the path as a string at the moment) to change the current working directory.

It also seems the command task uses the default execution thus you may want to specify that as `thread` here as well (changing the default to be more reasonable for command tasks in the future).